# AppCompat V21 spinner popup background is white with white text only in Android 4.0

Tags: android, spinner, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm using appcompat v21, and a style (theme) inherited from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar. The text and background are both white in the popup of the spinner. I've tested on Android 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, but this only happens on Android 4.0 (ICS). Is this a bug of appcompat v21? How can I change the background of all the spinners using theme style? Thanks.

This is the screenshot from my app having the issue on ICS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ1L3.png

[EDIT]

I Found it here that this is a bug currently having in appcompat v21

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78118&can=1&q=appcompat%20spinner&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create any background colored 9 patch image , and set it as a background of you spinner.
[image]

and set it in background of your spinner.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blueSpinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:popupBackground="@drawable/blueSpinner"
    />
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: Quite off-topic, but you may want to update *linkedin* link in your profile. :)